# How to get data from Nodejs to angular 6?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, http, angular6

I'm using http.get to get data from nodejs to angular. I want load some content on page loading. So, I'm just calling it in initialize method.

```
_initialize(): void {
this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/query/getId').subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log("success");
  },
  err => {
    console.log("Error occured."+JSON.stringify(err));
  }
);
}
```

In my server js,

```
app.get('/query/getId',function(req,res){
             console.log("hi there");

 })
```

I want to pass the data, but as of now the console message itself not displaying in node.  And in browser I could see the message error occured. message":"Http failure during parsing for the url" . Can anybody tell me how to proceed with this?

Comment: That's because Angular expects to get JSON back from your server, but at the moment it doesn't. If you modify your server to send back some basic JSON (even just an empty object like `res.send('{}')`) then that error should go away

Comment: still getting the same error message":"Http failure during parsing for the url" @user184994

Comment: If you check in the browsers developer tools (F12) and check the network tab for the request, can you see the response that's coming back?

Comment: status code is 200 & in response tab "your browser doesnt support javascript" @user184994

Answer (score 0):

Add on node function:

```
res.json("hi there");
```

Comment: still getting the same error like "message":"Http failure during parsing for the url"

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that the data to be returned is not a **`JSON`** using the **`responseType`**. See the **[`Requesting non JSON data`](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data)**

In your example, you should be able to use:

```
 this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/query/getId',{}, {responseType: 'text'})
```

Comment: I want json response only.. But after returning json data also I'm getting same error like "message":"Http failure during parsing for the url" .

Comment: ok in that case set the headers to application json and inspect your network tab what is being sent and recieved

Comment: In network tab. Im getting status code 200. But still I'm facing he same error.

Comment: are you using angular 6 with httpclient?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following which uses JSON data:

```
app.get('/query/getId',function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
 });
```